# Conjugate poles of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let district $D$ be symmetrical about $x$ axis, $f$ meromorphic on $D$, $f(D\cap \mathbb {R})\subset \mathbb {R} \cup \{\infty\}$. Show that if $z_0\in D$ is a pole of $f$, then $\overline {z_0}$ is also a pole of $f$, and there exists $Res(f,\overline {z_0})=\overline {Res(f,z_0)}$.

---

Actually I have no idea of solving this. I tried to prove that $\lim_{z\to \overline {z_0}} f(z)=\infty$ but I cannot continue at showing $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(\bar {z})=\infty$.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset D$ be the poles of $f$. Then f is holomorphic on $\Omega := D\setminus\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Now the [Schwarz reflection princple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle)  asserts that $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ on $\Omega$. Fix a pole $z_k$. Then $f$ has Laurent series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(z-z_k)^n
$$
in a punctured neighborhood of $z_k$, with $c_{-1}=\text{Res}(f,z_k)$. However it follows that
$$
f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{c}_n(z-\bar{z}_k)^n
$$
is the Laurent series of $f$ in a neighborhood of $\bar{z}_k$, since $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$. Now it is clear that $\bar{c}_{-1}=\text{Res}(f,\bar{z}_k)$, as desired.

Comment: Excellent job using Schwarz

Comment: generally,$\omega$ is not a region,so how to use identity theorem of analytic?

Comment: The set of poles must be discrete, so when you subtract it from D it should still be a region. As long as your definition of a region is an open connected set. I guess I'm also assuming that D is a region, although it wasn't mentioned.